# how to apply filter on excel file in c# (asp.net mvc)

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, asp.net-mvc-5, epplus

i need to filter an excel file that i fetch information from it
in my mvc web Application .
which package should i install , or which feature i should use? which command?
advance appreciated.
this is my code :

```
 public ActionResult Upload(FormCollection formCollection)
        {
            var CourseList= new List<CourseTbl>();
            if (Request != null)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["UploadedFile"];
                if ((file != null) && (file.ContentLength > 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
                {
                    string fileName = file.FileName;
                    string fileContentType = file.ContentType;
                    byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                    var data = file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(file.ContentLength));
                    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file.InputStream))
                    {
                        ExcelWorksheets currentSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets;
                        ExcelWorksheet workSheet = currentSheet.First();
                        //i attempt below commands : (not worked)
                        //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.AutoFilter
                        //workSheet.Cells.AutoFilter
                        var noOfCol = workSheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                        var noOfRow = workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                        for (int rowIterator = 2; rowIterator <= noOfRow; rowIterator++)
                        {
                            var Course = new CourseTbl();
                            Course.Course_id = Convert.ToInt32(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 1].Value);
                            Course.name = Convert.ToString(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 2].Value);
                            CourseList.Add(Course);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            using (ExcelImportDBEntities excelImportDBEntities = new ExcelImportDBEntities())
            {
                foreach (var item in CourseList)
                {
                    excelImportDBEntities.darsTbls.Add(item);
                }
                excelImportDBEntities.SaveChanges();
            }
            return View("Index");
         }
```

Comment: What do you mean by filter? Where do you want to apply your filter and what do you want to filter?

Comment: Imagine you have an excel file , and one column could be filtered , i want to do this filtering immediately from my webapplication . Was i able to tell my purpose clearly?

Comment: One way is to generate a list of unique entries for the column of interest and then use this to create a drop down list in you web interface which you can then use via JavaScript/jQuery to modify your display. A quick Google will find examples like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_filters.asp)